# Image Plane with Alpha Transparency, I want to remove lighting effects

Tags: materials, image, transparency, lighting

I'm trying to do a multi plane image effect in blender. I want the image textures to render, with 0 lighting effects, so basically like an emission texture, but I can't use emission, because I want the paintings to have alpha channels.

[image]

As you can see, I have them side by side. I don't want to light these images, cause I don't want shadows cast on one another. I just want them to be the correct color, but with the alpha channel applied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mix your Image texture (through a shader - emission is possible) with a Transparent Shader, using your images' alpha as a mix factor. As you can see in the image bleow, there are no lights in the scene. It works in both cycles and EEVEE, but keep in mind, in Cycles it will actually emit light without further modification to the shader. If using EEVEE, remember to switch the material's blend mode to something other than *opaque*:

[image: Alpha]

Comment: Interesting nodes. Thanks.

Comment: DUDE thank you! Praise you and your pot leaf!